# how can i use workspace 'typescript.tsdk' in mutipule dir

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a nextjs project and a strapi in a 'package' Folder，in nextjs project i want to use typescript version with node_modules/typescript/lib. What should I do？
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7jPx.png)

in nextjs project use nextjs tsdk.